# Error with a valid geojson when try to split the file with ndjson-split

Tags: npm, geojson, ndjson

I want to remove all the properties from my geojson file so for that I first try to make a ndjson file like that:

```
/root/npm/bin/ndjson-split 'd.features' < test.json > test.ndjson
```

but I get this error:

```
stdin:1
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

My geojson is a valid one, it's just here: https://gist.github.com/2803media/b52c9078c6c7932396ce6b42d7f0073e

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After test it seem to be a bug if the geojson is format with break line, the trick if to use convert to topojson and back to geojson